# How to create a UISegmentedControl with one momentary button?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to have a UISegmentedControl with a number of selectable options in it, but also include an Info button, which is not selectable. The UISegmentedControl class reference talks about using a momentary disclosure button, hinting that its possible, but there is nothing else there or in the header file that explains how to do such a thing.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation, I found that keeping a shadow variable on the selected index let me do this. In the following code, the info button is 1, the other buttons are selectable. In `viewDidLoad` set the initial value (or ask the control for its selected index). Then use the following code for the action method:

```
- (IBAction)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSUInteger idx = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];
    switch(idx) {
    case 1:  // momentary button
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex;
        break;
    default:
        selectedIndex = idx;
        // other stuff
        break;
    }
    ...
```

Essentially all you need to do is reset the selected index. Tested with iOS7 only.